# How does using an if statement after an elif statement work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This simply a concept question. In a chain of if statements what would happen in the following chain? if-elif-if. I am not sure how the code will flow with the if statement after the elif.

Comment: Please give a meaningful example. Or even better: Try it out yourself

Comment: Anything other than an `elif` or `else`, at the same indentation level as the original `if`, terminates the entire statement.  Another `if` has no special meaning at that point, it's just the start of a new statement.

Comment: Thank you, @jasonharper. That seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an `if` statement after an `elif`, this means this a different block of if statements. For example, if I do

```
yes = "yes"
no = "no"

if yes == "yes":
    print("yee")
elif no == "no":
    print(":(")
```

It will only print "yee" as after it stopped after the first one worked. However, if we do this:

```
if yes == "yes":
    print("yee")
if no == "no":
    print(":(")
```

Both will print as they are two different statements with no correspondence to each other.